# "owner": "typescript", "message": "Object is possibly 'null'.", "startColumn": 26, "endLineNumber": 12,

Tags: angular, typescript, guard

I have this type error in auth Service :

```
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); // get token from local storage
    const payload = btoa(token.split('.')[1]); // decode payload of token
    const parsedPayload = JSON.parse(payload); // convert payload into an Object

    return parsedPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000; // check if token is expired
  }
```

The error is :
`btoa(token.split('.')[1]);`

And the error shows in btoa and token it says **Object is possibly 'null'**.

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear to you? The error simply states that this statement can possibly produce an error when the `token` is `null`. `localStorage.getItem()` returns `string | null`, so you're not always guarranteed a value.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually pretty simple and just tells you that you are accessing values which *may* be `undefined | null` and therefore would cause a runtime error (say `undefined.split('.')` for example).
Easiest solution is to add more checks to each step to prevent those errors and make the compiler happy:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); // The token returned *may* be null, therefore you need to make sure it is defined for `token.split` to work
if (token !== null) {
  const payload = btoa(token.split('.')[1]);
  // Depending on the token, [1] may return undefined if there were no findings to split on
  if (payload !== undefined) {
    const parsedPayload = JSON.parse(payload);
    return parsedPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
  }
}

return null; // Handle this where you use the function accordingly. If you returned null, something was wrong with the token.
```